# Streaming over RTSP using nodejs

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to stream a (.mp4) file through my nodejs server using RTSP. I searched a lot and got stumbled upon this:

[node-rstp-server](https://github.com/iizukanao/node-rtsp-rtmp-server)

which really looks promising.

I tried streaming the video over rtsp and testing in VLC media player as provided in the docs like: rtps://localhost:8080/video.mp4 and the vlc is unable to play any video. The doc for the above says that you can access streamed video using file path directly which clearly doesn't work over RTSP.

I did some more research and found that RTSP requires a SDP to be constructed first. What is the best way to construct a proper SDP and then RTSP it on a specific port using a path.

`(e.g rstp://112.332.3.1:8493/someFilePath)`

Excuse the terminology if it looks a bit weird, I am new to all this. I am working in a nodejs ecosystem on the server side which can easily implement a ffmpeg and my client is going to be a simple html5 app over cordova.

Answer (score 0):

If you are broadcasting over rtsp, make sure to change your Live555 stream transport option from HTTP (default) to RTP over RTSP (TCP) in vlc's input/codecs preferences for vlc to receive rtsp. Following are the steps to follow

1. Tools menu, click Preferences.
2. In the Simple Preferences dialog box, click Input / Codecs in the contents panel.
3. In Input & Codecs Settings, in the Network area, change the Live555 stream transport option from HTTP (default) to RTP over RTSP (TCP).
4. Click Save.